# Como inserir uma linha em um gráfico do gnuplot py?

Tags: python-2.7

Eu quero inserir uma linha no meio de um gráfico que estou plotando com o Gnuplot (python),que vai servir como threshold, como, por exemplo, em y = 0. Como eu posso fazer isso?

Answer (score 0):

Descobri a maneira.

Basta incluir uma seta, contando a posição inicial e final, e por fim dizendo que ela não precisa ter ponta, como no exemplo abaixo:

```
g('set arrow from <initial position x,y> to <final position x,y> nohead')
```